# Angular component is not released in page navigation on Chrome Dev Tool

Tags: angular, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory, angular11

I created fresh Angular 11 project and then added two pages with only one div covering the whole page as followings:

##### // pour page

```html
// component.html
<div style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background: cyan;" (click)="onClick()"></div>
```

```js
// component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pour-page',
  templateUrl: './pour-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pour-page.component.scss']
})
export class PourPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onClick() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('selector');
  }
}
```

##### // selector page

```html
// component.html
<div style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background: yellow;" (click)="onClick()"></div>
```

```js
// component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-selector',
  templateUrl: './selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selector.component.scss']
})
export class SelectorComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onClick() {
    this.router.navigateByUrl('pour-page');
  }
}
```

I tried to check memory snapshot on chrome dev tool but it is showing different results in inspector mode and non-inspector mode.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in above screenshots, in inspector mode(which has touch enabled), it is showing memory leaks while it is not in non-inspector mode.

Is this known bug in inspector mode? I really couldn't figure out what's wrong with it.